# Calibre - display cover size on main screen

Tags: calibre, cover

Is there any way to add a column with the dimension of the cover on the main screen?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this? Perhaps you could post an image showing what you're trying to do.

Comment: When you pull up the library and have the list of books with the treeview on the left - you have columns like name, author, publisher, ....

I'd like to be able to have column there that tells me what the dimensions are of the cover. This way I know if there are some I need to convert so it will display correctly on my Kindle HDX.

I already have the plug in to change the image size but I don't want to do it blindly because I might make the image smaller.